# Compute the derivative of $y = 2^{3^{x^{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the derivative of $$y = 2^{3^{x^{2}}}$$ using the chain rule?

Please show step by step solution.

Comment: what steps did you attempt on your own?

Comment: I'd start with writing the function in the base e, and then go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y = 2^{3^{x^{2}}}$$

$$y' = 2^{3^{x^{2}}}\ln2 (3^{x^{2}})'$$

$$y' = 2^{3^{x^{2}}}\ln2 (3^{x^{2}}\ln3)(x^2)'$$

$$y' = 2^{3^{x^{2}}}\ln2 (3^{x^{2}}\ln3)2x$$

$$y' = 2x\ln2 \ln3 2^{3^{x^{2}}}(3^{x^{2}})$$

$$y' = 2^{3^{x^{2}}}3^{x^{2}}2x\ln3\ln2 $$

Comment: Why didn't you leave in the (x^2) between step 3 and 4 as you did with the (3^(x^2)) between steps 2 and 3?

Comment: @user44816 He used the chain rule again, so he differentiated $(3^{x^2})$ into $((3^{x^2}\ln 3) (x^2)')$, and then at the next step he differentiated the last $x^2$.

Comment: If you are leaving in the (3^(x^2)) when differentiating (derivative is (ln3)(x^2), why wouldn't you leave in the (x^2) when differentiating at the next step (becomes 2x)? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: for a function $a^u$, $$\frac{d}{du} = a^u \ln a \cdot u'$$

In your case, $a=2, u = 3^{x^2}$.

Comment: Is $u=3^{x^2}$ not $u=3x^2$

Comment: Yup, typo. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{d}{dx}$? If the derivative were with respect to $u$ then $u'=1$ and there's no point writing it.

Comment: I replaced his function $3^{x^2}$ as $u$. If I were to write $\frac{d}{dx} a^{u}$, it would not make sense since you are not differentiating with respect to $u$. Also, consider the example with $u = x.$ Then $\frac{d}{du} = 2^x \ln 2$.